# difference between ' I go hungry all day.' and 'I am hungry all day.'

Tags: word-difference

I want to know the difference between ' I go hungry all day.' and 'I am hungry all day.'
What is the difference in meaning?

Comment: You have been a member of this community for almost three years. What is the reason that you don't explain what you understand and what you don't understand? What does your research show? What do you think "I am hungry all day" means? Did you Google "I go hungry all day"? In what context is the sentence used?

Answer (score 2):

This is a VERY subtle point of English.

"I go hungry" normally means that I do not eat. "I am hungry" means that I feel a need to eat, regardless of whether I have eaten recently or not. Thus, someone might say, "I am hungry all day even though I eat a big lunch". Meaning his lunch is not enough to satisfy his hunger, or it only satisfies his hunger for a brief time. But "I go hungry all day even though I eat a big lunch" doesn't make sense. You're saying that you don't eat and then you immediately say that you do eat.